# How to turn checkbox ariaChecked, to a boolean?

Tags: javascript

Whats the difference between this two different variable colors?

[image]

I`m trying to get then at the same type. The blue one is boolean, the other is an checkbox value. How to turn checkbox ariaChecked, to a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question correctly but it seems that checkbox value will by default be a string, that is why it is white.
To turn it to boolean you can create a variable and then check if values is the string `true`, the assign true to the variable, otherwise assign false.

```
const checkboxValue = ariaChecked === 'true' ? true : false;
```

or shorthand

```
const checkboxValue = ariaChecked === 'true';
```

Comment: Thanks, i just solved with Boolean().

Comment: @MayaRahto, Boolean() will convert truthy values to true and falsy to false. Any non empty string is truthy, thus will be converted to true. So, string false will be true if you do Boolean('false').